# table indices matching?

Tags: list-manipulation

is there a way I can do something like, if

```
h = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 1}]
```

so, I can access the 4th element of the h[[4]], so, what about going other way around that 3 is the fourth element.

Comment: `PositionIndex[h]@3` or `Position[h, 3]`?

Answer (score 1):

Position is actually a pretty useful function. Not only can it find specific values:

```
Position[h, 3]
```

(as suggested by kglr) but it can also be used to locate indices of ranges of values, for example:

```
Position[a, _?((2 < # < 5) &)]
```

or

```
Position[a, x_ /; (2 < x < 5)]
```

to locate all the indices with values between 2 and 5.